# Install Python package editable via PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

If I develop on linux I create a virtualenv, and then I install git repos like this:

```
pip install -e git+https://source.internal.lan/repos/foo#egg=foo
```

This installs package "foo" in $VIRTUAL_ENV/src/foo.

Now I have a project where I develop on windows.

On Windows I would like to do this via PyCharm.

How to do install package "foo" editable with PyCharm (without the command line)?

I a searching the equivalent GUI operations.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to do the exact same thing on windows?

Comment: @data on windows the command-line is very limited. I try to avoid it.

Comment: Are you asking for the sequence of GUI operations that are equivalent to the pip command?

Comment: "on windows the command-line is very limited". Strange. Pip runs just the same for me once you install it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, I am looking for GUI operations that are equivalent.

Comment: @MadPhysicist but ctrl-r is not available (my favourite trick of the gnu readline library)

Comment: Would you be willing to do it from the python shell? Pip is first and foremost a python module after all.

Comment: You can use the up and down arrows in CMD. It's not an advanced as bash, but quite functional for such a small task.

Comment: `CTRL`+`R` is available on Windows via amazing https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine. PSReadLine is included in Windows 10 but can be installed on older versions of system. More info here: https://serverfault.com/a/762222/100080.

Answer (score 2):

You could create `requirements.txt` with `-e git+https://source.internal.lan/repos/foo#egg=foo` inside and then PyCharm would suggest you to install `foo`.